# How to step through my script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I have a `rails runner` script I am attempting to debug. Currently I've got a bunch of `puts` statements showing me state/status but it's skipping a bunch of those statements and I don't know why. I want to debug and step through the lines and see what happens then.

I saw `pry` is one way to break out of execution but I don't know how to step in/out/over and examine variables.

I'm also a very big user of Jetbrains products and I figured I'd use the Rubymine debugger with breakpoints but it looks like it can only run vanilla ruby scripts, not `rails runner` scripts.

Suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I already said it in my original post:  I want to debug and step through the lines and see what happens. What tools do people typically use?

Comment: That question is an off-topic here on SO. People use different tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby#debugging-tools) is the list of most popular debugging tools in ruby. You can use them. Personally, I recommend you to start from `pry-byebug`

Answer (score 0):

Someone was nice enough to submit my question to Jetbrains and they were very helpful! Here's a screenshot of my debug config in my Windows environment:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-AR_BBqCg9qI/WhToSayDLuI/AAAAAAAAfX4/FS5ujyLWKKg2sO5qa5kCWT5Rtz8Bf7H6wCL0BGAYYCw/h498/2017-11-21.png

And THIS is an answer that addresses my question!